# How to get id of minprice in mysql query php

Tags: mysql

I want to select the exact id of the minprice in mysql query below in my mysql query

```
Select min(p.Price) as minprice,GROUP_CONCAT(p.vendor_id) as v_ids,p.* 
from my_table as p GROUP BY `SKU` order by Price ASC
```

I also tried this

```
Select min(p.Price) as minprice,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.PRODUCT_ID) as IDS,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.Price) as prices,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.vendor_id) as v_ids,p.* from `my_table` as p
  GROUP BY `SKU` order by Price ASC
```

but it does not help me out

Please to get the id of minprice

Comment: I need all results not all so that i can not use limit

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MT.* FROM MY_TABLE MT
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT PRODUCT_ID ID,SKU,MIN(P.PRICE) FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID,SKU
)Z ON Z.ID=MT.PRODUCT_ID AND Z.SKU=MT.SKU
```

You can try above code.